# BeautifulSoup - extracting particular element using filtering text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to webpage crawling, and I need to extract a particular element out of it, in this case `'Research Project – Cooperative Agreements'` right after the hyperlink in the data column.

I've been searching for `'Search_Type=Activity'` in the hyperlink using the following code:

```
for elem in soup(href=lambda href: href and "Search_Type=Activity" in href):
    print (elem.parent)
```

Because I'm crawling a bunch of NIH grant pages, and I need content of "Activity Code" and they all appear right after the hyperlink with terms 'Search_Type=Sctivity' in it.

So here is the HTML content that I've narrowed down using the code:

```
<div class="col-md-8 datacolumn"> <a href="//grants.nih.gov/grants/funding/ac_search_results.htm?text_curr=u01&amp;Search.x=0&amp;Search.y=0&amp;Search_Type=Activity">U01</a> Research Project – Cooperative Agreements
        <!--</div>
                </div> end row -->
<!-- If it is not the first row we close the previous row div tags -->
</div>
```

FYI, The original page used is just an NIH grant [here](https://grants.nih.gov/grants/guide/rfa-files/RFA-DK-19-501.html).
Could someone point out what that element is and how to get it out from there?

Comment: I'm not sure what your two lines of code are about, but why don't you use the search functionality of Beautiful Soup, [as documented](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#searching-the-tree)?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm crawling a bunch of pages for the content in 'Activity code', so they always appear right after the hyperlink with 'Search_Type=Activity' in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://grants.nih.gov/grants/guide/rfa-files/RFA-DK-19-501.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

name = (
    soup.select_one('[href*="Search_Type=Activity"]')
    .find_next_sibling(text=True)
    .strip()
)
print(name)
```

Prints:

```
Research Project – Cooperative Agreements
```